# Find empty space in silverlight canvas

Tags: silverlight, wpf-controls

I have a silverlight canvas that I have populated with boxes.  What I need to do then is find any empty space in the canvas as that will represent a gap in coverage (this is for a policy).  Is there any efficient way to do this?  I keep a list of children and there coordinates and I also have a two demensional grid keeping track of where everything is at.  I had origially accomplished this by looping through that grid but soon found that this wont work as the grids dimensions are around 800,1000 and thus gives me a ton of coordinates to check.  here is a screen shot of the canvas and the gap I need to find:

(correction:  I had an image but apparently I don't have enough reputation points to post it so my expectations of help were just lowered considerably)

The coordinates I keep for each child are top,left,width,height.  I also have the bounds of the canvas.  I'm thinking there has got to be an alrorithm somewhere to do this but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an odd thing to be trying to do! If you want to improve performance, why not render the canvas to a [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx). You can then iterate over each pixel in the image to determine whether it is an empty space based on color. The `WriteableBitmap` interface is a bit basic, so the [WriteableBitmapEx codeplex](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) project might be useful, it gives you a very simple 'get pixel at' method.

Comment: The problem is I actually need to do it before it renders.  What I am building is a kind of a chart (think tree map only more complex).  The canvas represents a coverage (i.e. auto liability...) and then each box is a policy.  The empty spaces represent a gap in coverage.  really wish I could post an image of it.